# What are existing theories on competing wills in the mind?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, reference-request

To clarify a little further, I've read in different places that our brain could be composed of mini minds, that preform all sorts of actions.  Assuming this is valid I'd think that of these minds, some result in a composite or layering that results in our personality and an ultimate will that wins out to complete some action or decision, insomuch as a set of minds are inter-related in relation to some function.

I'm really just assuming from reading various articles and papers and some personal self reflection... but I'd imagine there is something to read in relation to this idea in some shape or form.... In other words I'm looking for more solid reading material, I'm not sure what I should be searching for.

Comment: Re: "I've read in different places" - can you provide some references?  There are many different ways that the brain can be divided where parts "compete" for dominance: Dual process theory, corpus callosotomy, adaptive unconscious, schemata, etc, so it would help to see what are the "mini minds" being referred to.

Comment: That's kind of the problem it's been a while since I've read about it probably some place like new scientist or some other pop sci publication, didn't think much of it at the time but was curious about the idea.  Really I'm looking for possibilities so I can start doing some googling to figure out what I am looking for. Perhaps some of the theories you are mentioning will be it.  I can see that my question isn't precise was hoping someone might recognize what I am referring too, but maybe the question is too broad.

Comment: Now you have me wondering if I'm making this up...

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg how about modular cognition? Also, is there a theory that can possibly reduce to those theories? Or are they still incompatible with each other?

Comment: @Ooker I must have missed your comment about modular cognition wish I saw that when we were on this topic. I came across this in an article I read today.  This is what I was looking for.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_of_mind

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pointing you to existing theories, which is (1) too advanced for you to understand at the current level of knowledge, and (2) too focused so that you don't have a big picture, why don't we just suggest you to read a textbook about cognition? It will solve both problems at the same time.

I recommend the book **Cognitive Psychology**, written by Strenberg, as the starting point. **Cognition: Exploring the Science** (author: Reisberg) is also a good one. If you are like me, you will realize how to make the question clearer just after some first few pages of reading.

Comment: That's great advice thank you.  I actually just purchased this book a few days ago, https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1841695351/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1, I am adding these others to my list.

Comment: I think the book I've bought is probably going to send me a different direction than these others, but it was bought with a different intent in mind.  Again thank you, I'm always on the lookout for good book recommendations.

Comment: neuroscience is more about brain functions and stuff. Typically if you just want to have an insight on your daily activity, (cognitive) psychology is more applicable.

Comment: Yes I shared that book with you too quick or without looking yours over as closely as I should have. My learning focus has been on neuroscience. This question was just something I had in the back of my mind and was wondering, and thought I'd ask while being active here.  I haven't focused on psychology as much.

Answer (score 0):

Two theories that can elaborate on your initial question would be:

1. Norman and Shallice model on executive function. Specifically the component described as supervisory attentional system:

Norman, D. A., & Shallice, T. (1986). Attention to action. In Consciousness and self-regulation (pp. 1-18). Springer, Boston, MA.

2. Leon Festingers concept of cognitive dissonance:

Festinger, L. (1962). A theory of cognitive dissonance (Vol. 2). Stanford university press.

Comment: Thank you I will review these.